# Get ReceivedFileName from context in BizTalk via SQL

Tags: duplicates, filenames, biztalk

We have a BizTalk integration that generates invoices from an Excelfile, these Excelfiles are handled manually and sometimes they will get dropped twice into the receive location, causing duplicates of invoices that then needs to be handled, sometimes thousands of invoices.

My wish is to prevent BizTalk from processing a file that already has been processed.

I have C#-code that extracts the properties from Context. But to be able to use that code I would have to get all Context for this Port into the C#-code and search for the new file that arrived. This would cause a lot of unnecessary data to be transported on the network.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Stored Procedure in a database that takes a filename as parameter and returns true/false as to whether it has been received earlier or not.
Currently I'm looking at Context in the table `[BizTalkDTADb].[dbo].[btsv_Tracking_Spool]` which I know contains the filename of the received file.

```
DECLARE @StartDate as datetime = '2021-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate as datetime = '2021-01-31'
DECLARE @MyPortName as nvarchar(255) = 'Prt.RcvExcel'

SELECT 
app.nvcName as BizTalkApplication, 
'ReceivePort' as PortType, 
tspool.imgContext as 'Context', 
TrackingData.uidMessageInstanceId as MessageID,
TrackingData.dtTimestamp as MyTimeStamp, 
TrackingData.nPortId, 
TrackingData.dtInsertionTimeStamp as MyInsertTimeStamp
FROM .BizTalkDTADb.dbo.dta_MessageInOutEvents AS TrackingData WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN .BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_receiveport rp WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN .BizTalkDTADb.dbo.dta_PortName pp WITH (NOLOCK) ON rp.nvcName = pp.strPortName ON
TrackingData.nPortId = pp.nPortId
INNER JOIN .BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_application app WITH (NOLOCK) ON rp.nApplicationID = app.nID
INNER JOIN .BizTalkDTADb.dbo.btsv_Tracking_Spool tspool WITH (NOLOCK) ON tspool.uidMsgID = TrackingData.uidMessageInstanceId
WHERE TrackingData.nStatus=0 AND TrackingData.dtInsertionTimeStamp > @StartDate AND TrackingData.dtInsertionTimeStamp < @EndDate AND
pp.strPortName = @MyPortName
```

How can I achieve this in SQL? Or is there a smarter way doing this inside an orchestration using some built in functionality? I have the name of the received file in the orchestration.

Comment: I would suggest creating a database with a table where you can insert the received files you want to prevent duplicates off and also have the stored procedure there to check for the duplicate.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a database/table that needs maintanence, but it is a solution.

A table that contains a timestamp and a filename. It would even be possible to skip the stored procedure and do a simple count(*)-query, if it returns a number greater than 0 the file has been sent earlier. Then a job that removes entries older than a specific time.

Comment: Ideally it is the end system that the invoices are being sent to should do the duplicate check, and only in BizTalk as a last resort, as there are other scenarios like retries on a send port that can cause duplicates.    Unfortunately there is no built in functionality in BizTalk for doing duplicate checks.  So either a custom table, or you would have to put that stored procedure with your logic in another DB anyway, as you shouldn't be altering the BizTalk DBs.

Comment: That is the main problem, the end system sometimes gets thousands of duplicate invoices if a file is dropped twice into the receive location for BizTalk. These duplicates must be handled manually one by one by administrators. It is only at the receive location I want to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Instead of a boolean true/false to indicate if a file has been processed I suggest returning a datetime type or null. If it was processed before you know when. I frequently get questions from users wanting explanations why something happened. If I can tell them "processed already at such and such time" they are more accepting and it  helps track down what happened

Comment: Good idea, otherwise we'll probably get a lot of cases where the customer insists on never having send the file.